# How to work with two data frames that interact with each other inside one function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, mutated

I get the below output when I run my custom function `runLabel()` against starting data frame `myDF`, generated via the code immediately beneath. The code generates two data frames: `Label` and `selGrpCode`, and `Label` needs to be manipulated by values in `selGrpCode` resulting in a new `matchOnes` column added (mutated) to the `Label` data frame. But the `matchOnes` column does not appear in the `Label` data frame.

```
> runLabel(myDF)
  Element Group eleCnt eleGrpCnt grpPrefix subGrpRnk grpCode
1       R     0      1         0         0         0     0.0
2       R     0      2         0         0         0     0.0
3       B     0      1         0         0         0     0.0
4       R     0      3         0         0         0     0.0
5       X     1      1         1         1         1     1.1
6       X     1      2         1         2         2     2.2
  grpCode
1     1.1
2     2.2

library(dplyr)

myDF <- data.frame(
    Element = c("R","R","B","R","X","X"),
    Group = c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
  )

runLabel <- function(x) {Label <- x %>%
  group_by(Element) %>%
    mutate(eleCnt = row_number()) %>%
    mutate(eleGrpCnt = ifelse(Group != 0,match(Group, unique(Group)),0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(grpPrefix = eleCnt * eleGrpCnt) %>%
  mutate(subGrpRnk = ifelse(Group > 0, sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Element[1:x]==Element[x] & Group[1:x] == Group[x])),0)) %>%
  mutate(grpCode = as.numeric(paste(grpPrefix,subGrpRnk, sep = '.')))

selGrpCode <- Label %>% distinct(grpCode) %>% select(grpCode) %>% filter(grpCode > 0) %>% arrange(grpCode)

Label %>% mutate(matchOnes = ifelse(eleCnt < min(selGrpCode),eleCnt,0))

print.data.frame(Label)
print.data.frame(selGrpCode)
}
```

This is how `Label` data frame should present (adding the missing column to the right):

```
  Element Group eleCnt eleGrpCnt grpPrefix subGrpRnk grpCode matchOnes
1       R     0      1         0         0         0     0.0         1
2       R     0      2         0         0         0     0.0         0
3       B     0      1         0         0         0     0.0         1
4       R     0      3         0         0         0     0.0         0
5       X     1      1         1         1         1     1.1         1
6       X     1      2         1         2         2     2.2         0
```

How do I adjust the function so that two data frames can be run and interact? Using dplyr where possible. Please don't simplify by reducing this to one data frame, because this code is a simplification of more involved code and needs to run two data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save your `Label` variable at the end, otherwise the mutation is not printed from your function:

```r
runLabel <- function(x) {
      ...
      Label <- Label %>% mutate(matchOnes = ifelse(eleCnt < min(selGrpCode),eleCnt,0))
      ...
}
```

And here your full code:

```r
library(dplyr)

myDF <- data.frame(
  Element = c("R","R","B","R","X","X"),
  Group = c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
)

runLabel <- function(x) {
  Label <- x %>%
  group_by(Element) %>%
  mutate(eleCnt = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(eleGrpCnt = ifelse(Group != 0,match(Group, unique(Group)),0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(grpPrefix = eleCnt * eleGrpCnt) %>%
  mutate(subGrpRnk = ifelse(Group > 0, sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Element[1:x]==Element[x] & Group[1:x] == Group[x])),0)) %>%
  mutate(grpCode = as.numeric(paste(grpPrefix,subGrpRnk, sep = '.')))

selGrpCode <- Label %>% distinct(grpCode) %>% select(grpCode) %>% filter(grpCode > 0) %>% arrange(grpCode)

Label <- Label %>% mutate(matchOnes = ifelse(eleCnt < min(selGrpCode),eleCnt,0))

print.data.frame(Label)
print.data.frame(selGrpCode)
}

runLabel(myDF)
#>   Element Group eleCnt eleGrpCnt grpPrefix subGrpRnk grpCode matchOnes
#> 1       R     0      1         0         0         0     0.0         1
#> 2       R     0      2         0         0         0     0.0         0
#> 3       B     0      1         0         0         0     0.0         1
#> 4       R     0      3         0         0         0     0.0         0
#> 5       X     1      1         1         1         1     1.1         1
#> 6       X     1      2         1         2         2     2.2         0
#>   grpCode
#> 1     1.1
#> 2     2.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I should have known better. Welcome to Stack!